# Roo 2.0.0 how to add an addon from jar?

Tags: spring, spring-roo

I want to use a Spring Roo addon for Timestamp.  https://github.com/rcaloras/spring-roo-addon-timestamp

The instructions are

```
osgi start --url file://$PATH_TO_DOWNLOAD/com.rcaloras.roo.addon.timestamp-0.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
timestamp setup
timestamp all
```

But roo replies

> Command not found for osgi. Has this changed for 2.0.0?

I have also tried addon install bundle, addon install url, but to no avail.  I've downloaded the jar file, but don't know how to get roo to recognize the addon.  OR, is there a way to install an addon via spring STS in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This add-on is developed to install it on Spring Roo 1.2.5. You can't install it on 2.0. Spring Roo 2.0 has [mayor changes](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO/fixforversion/14835) that makes it impossible (included a [OSGi upgrade](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3597) and a new system to [handle add-ons](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3600)).

Also, keep in mind current Spring Roo 2.0.0 is a *Milestone*, not a final release. It's not recommended for production environments.

On another hand, [gvNIX](http://www.gvnix.org/en/index.html) jpa add-on can help you. This is developed for Spring Roo 1.3.0, and includes a add-on which includes this functionality (`jpa audit setup`, `jpa audit add` and `jpa audit all`). In addition this add-on can integrate your application with [Hibernate Envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/) to store all changes on your entities (`jpa audit revisionLog`).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I didn't realize that gvNIX had this.  I'm already using gvNIX 2.0.0 - but I hadn't translated the doc for this feature.  I'll look at Envers too. Do you know if there is any English-based support/forums for gvNIX? On your other point, roo primarily generates java code and can be removed, so what is the risk in using a milestone release of it?

Comment: This (SO) is the right way to get support  ;-) (also for gvNIX too, there is a tag for it). About Milestione release: Roo 2.0 is about change generated project structure drastically (see https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/30/looking-ahead-to-spring-roo-2-0) , so, if you found a bug in it that requires changes on roo itself, you will get no compatible version as branch has been changes. Of course, in this case, you always can make any change directly on your project, using push-in or don't use Roo console any more.